# 404 and 401 errors in the ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using jQuery's ajax method to submit an ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: someURL,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: "json"
     })
```

How can I add error handlers for the http status codes 401 and 404?

Comment: RTFM, would make it easier for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you can implement handlers for specific status code responses as options when calling `.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: someURL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            // handle the 404 response
        },
        401: function() {
            // handle the 401 response
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Look at the docs for goodness sake.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **statusCode (default: {})**
>
> Type: PlainObject
>
> An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>     statusCode: {
>         404: function() {
>             alert( "page not found" );
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error (including 3xx redirect), they take the same parameters as the error callback.
>   (version added: 1.5)

It's really simple to find an answer if you look at the documentation that describes the behavior of a method.